# pasar un formulario de un controlador a una vista laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hola tengo un controlador que genera un form en html y me gustaría porder pasar a una vista y que me lo reconozca como contenido html no como una cadena de texto.
mi codigo en el controlador seria este $form es el formulario que quiero mostrar

```
    $datos['form_pago']= $form;
    $datos['precio']= $precio;
    $datos['producto']= $producto;
    return view('pago')->with('datos', $datos);
```

y en la vista tendria el siguiente codigo

```
    {!! htmlspecialchars($datos['form_pago']) !!}
```

es posible realizar esto con laravel?

sin pasarlo a la vista desde el controlador haciendo un echo veo lo siguiente en esa varaible tengo lo que devuelve este metodo de redsys 
[image: aqui dejo la imagen de lo que devuelve]

Comment: Lo probaste y no funciona?

Comment: me he puesto dentro de un div y me puestra el html del formulario pero todo entre comillas.
"<label>
<input type='text'>"
de esta forma me lo printa

Comment: aqui dejo la imagen del inspector de lo que veo en el inspector de elementos sin pasar la variable a la vista

Comment: Prueba con `{!! $datos['form_pago'] !!}` o `{!! htmlentities($datos['form_pago']) !!}`

Comment: {!! $datos['form_pago'] !!} con esta forma si funciona muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como muestras en la imagen, en tu variable tienes un `string` con etiquetas HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces para mostrar esos datos sin que blade quite esas etiquetas, debes usar la sintaxis de [visualización de datos sin escapes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data)

Por defecto, las declaraciones Blade `{{ }}` se envían automáticamente a través de la función `htmlspecialchars` de PHP para evitar ataques XSS. Si no desea que se escapen sus datos, puede usar la siguiente sintaxis:

```
{!! $datos['form_pago'] !!}
```

**Nota Importante**: Tenga mucho cuidado al hacer `echo` del contenido que proporcionan los usuarios de su aplicación. Utilice siempre la sintaxis de doble llaves escapado para evitar ataques XSS cuando muestre datos proporcionados por el usuario.